# Genymotion Error: "Unable to load VirtualBox Engine" on Yosemite. VirtualBox installed

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, osx-yosemite, genymotion

I have a Macbook Pro 13 inch with OS X Yosemite [Memory 8 GB, Graphics Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB]. I am trying to setup Genymotion as Android Emulator.
I installed Oracle VirtualBox first from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads [VirtualBox-5.0.0-101573-OSX.dmg], and then Genymotion for personal use from [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) [genymotion-2.5.0.dmg].

But I get the following error -

[image: Unable to load VirtualBox engine]

I checked all the previous answers on StackOverflow and the Google search results, and I did the following, but none of them solved the problem.

**1.** 
(a)

> sudo /Library/Startupitems/VirtualBox/VirtualBox restart

OR
(b)

> sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart

Since my **/Library/Startupitems/** is empty, I tried option (b).

**2.** 
Open **VirtualBox -> Preferences -> Network**, Under "**Host-only Networks**", I deleted the one that was listed.
Under "**Nat Networks**", there is an Active network called "**NatNetwork**", which is checked.

**3.** 
*vboxmanage* is added to path & has nothing under *hostonlyifs*

Terminal:

```
$ which vboxmanage
/usr/local/bin/vboxmanage

$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: <others>

$ vboxmanage list hostonlyifs
## no output - prints nothing
```

These are all I found through Google Search. How do I get the Genymotion working for Yosemite ?

{ If possible, please provide a solution that is not too technical, since I am new to Mac, and it might also help people using Mac for the first time. I know this is not a new question on StackOverflow. But none of the previous posts had helped me. }

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check the compatible VM version https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#compatible-virtualbox-versions

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I had the problem that VBoxManage was installed at /usr/local/bin/ which was not in the path for GUI apps.
I did:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage /usr/bin/VBoxManage
```

Comment: Ok this is interesting! When VirtualBox 4.3.30 and 5.0 versions didn't work for me, vboxmanage was in /usr/local/bin/, and VirtualBox 4.3.28 worked and its vboxmanage was in /usr/bin/ for me! So this means that the location of vboxmanage was causing the error ? Both /usr/local/bin and /usr/bin are in PATH; so I don't know why it should matter !

Comment: OS X has different paths for GUI vs console apps, both /etc/paths and .profile do not work for GUI apps :(

Comment: sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage /usr/bin/VBoxManage - worked for me on OS X 10.11

Comment: @Nekromancer mching's was the first answer, and before this answer was posted, I had already fixed the issue by using VBox 4.3 as suggested by mching, so that is why, it was accepted earlier.

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me! i must've tried 10 other "tips" posted around the web, but only this worked! also keep in mind that genymotion is recommending [VirtualBox 5.0.26](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.26/VirtualBox-5.0.26-108824-OSX.dmg) as of July 31, 2017

Comment: Not working on OSX 10.13.1, tried many VirtualBox versions. 4.3, 5.0, 5.1.3

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same problem, Use VirtualBox 4.3 instead of 5.0
That did the trick for me.

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox 4.3 are you using ? I tried with VirtualBox 4.3.30 and it didn't work. Same problem.

Comment: Ok, VirtualBox 4.3.28 worked! Thanks a lot :) Not sure why newer versions aren't compatible.

Answer (score 6):

This work for me:

1. Remove current Virtual version and install VirtualBox version 4.3.
2. Run terminal and execute this line:

> sudo /Library/Application\
>   Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart

3. Continue this line:

> sudo cp /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage /usr/bin/VBoxManage

Now can run Genymotion.

Answer (score 6):

I tried all these and nothing working with me except this one

VirtualBox from the unidentified developer so OSX refuse to install it so you need unlock this option from Security and privacy --> general tab

[image]

reference

https://medium.com/@DMeechan/fixing-the-installation-failed-virtualbox-error-on-mac-high-sierra-7c421362b5b5

Answer (score 5):

```
brew cask install virtualbox
```

I had this issue after upgrading to OS X 10.11.1 moving to Virtual Box 5.0.8 fixed it

Comment: Installing virtual box and then setting the symbolic link worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I've reported it on Google Groups [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=pl&fromgroups#!topic/genymotion-users/3sNkE-2Onjc). I think for now there is no other way then downgrading - we have to wait for update.

Comment: In the Google Group you linked to, Samuel said it is supposed to work with VirtualBox 5.0. I think the problem is only with location of VBoxManage in PATH (but I don't know why that would be a problem). Check Moritz's answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31379463/1682975

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue updating Genymotion to Genymotion 2.5.1

Answer (score 2):

In my case I just update VirtualBox from 4.3 to 5.0
https://www.virtualbox.org

this issue occurs after update to OS X El Capitan 10.11.4

Answer (score 2):

Although this is one year later, this worked for me on mac (after switching from windows). Just install virtual box 5.0. (Or whatever is the latest version at time of reading this).

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. The symlink did not work because my installation is already in `/usr/bin` Instead, I went to [the VirtualBox Downloads section](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), selected the amd64 link for OS X, opened it, ran the pkg installer. By default, it installed overtop of the existing app. So I opened VirtualBox and got some weird error that I totally ignored. Then went to Genymotion and everything worked, perfectly.