# Genymotion "Virtualization Engine Not Found" error after upgrading to El Capitan

Tags: genymotion, osx-elcapitan

Virtualbox and Genymotion are up-to-date.

I can create and start VMs in Virtualbox.

System Integrity Protection is enabled.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 21):

Upgrading or installing VirtualBox fixed it:

1. Download from here: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
2. Open the dmg (mac)
3. Run the uninstaller
4. Run the installer

Answer (score 3):

same here. Genymotion on El-Capitan is completely broken. Tried several Virtual box versions (4.3 5.0) and the latest genymotion 2.5.2. Still no luck.

Update: Finally got it working using this:

sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/vboxmanage /usr/bin/vboxmanage

See:
[Genymotion Error: "Unable to load VirtualBox Engine" on Yosemite. VirtualBox installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364475/genymotion-error-unable-to-load-virtualbox-engine-on-yosemite-virtualbox-ins)

Comment: as of nov 2016, genymotion 2.8 + virtual box 5.1.8 failed me big time. downloaded geny 2.5.2 and vb 5.0.28 and things worked right out the box. geny 2.5.2 https://dl.genymotion.com/releases/genymotion-2.5.2/genymotion-2.5.2.dmg vb 5.0.28 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.28/VirtualBox-5.0.28-111378-OSX.dmg in case someone's after the urls.